# if statement or else

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hello I work on this code

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "X " OrElse

   Not ComboBox14.SelectedItem = "Every 15 Sec" OrElse
   Not ComboBox15.SelectedItem = "F" Then

    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox1.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox2.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox4.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox4.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox5.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox5.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox6.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox6.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox7.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox7.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox8.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox8.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox9.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox9.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox10.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox10.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox11.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox11.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox12.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox12.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox13.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox13.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox14.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox14.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ComboBox15.SelectedItem = "" Then

    Else
        ComboBox15.Enabled = False
    End If
Else

End If
```

Here I have 15 `ComboBox`, so if I clicked and checked this values from `ComboBox`, that would disable all `ComboBox`es,

For example if I choose"B (Recommended)" in `ComboBox1`,

then this will disable all `ComboBox`,

=-=-=-

> it only works when I choose "X (Recommended)" from first `ComboBox1`

-=-

I tried `or` , `Else` , and finally `OrElse Not`

and not good results until now.

Comment: I formatted your code so that it's at least readable. You're welcome. Do it for us yourself in future.

Comment: thanks @jmcilhinney, but please write it back ,,

you edited my post ,, and it work now,, i want to make it answered by you,, 

so please Write it back to mark it answered thanks for your help

Comment: As for the code, it's crazy. You need to understand logic a bit better before trying to write code. Think about this. Let's say that I have a room full of people and I say that everyone who is not 20 years old or else is not 30 years old should leave the room, how many people will be left? Judging by your code, you would not have said zero, but that's the answer. Any time you OR two mutually exclusive conditions, you automatically match everything. You need to think through your logic first.  Try it with fewer variables first. Once you understand the logic, THEN write the code.

Comment: i cant see how to make it answer by comment,, please write it again as add As answer Question to make it answered , thanks

Comment: I didn't change your code.  All I did was format it for readability. If it works now then it worked before but nothing I did will make the logic sound.

Comment: oh you right , i must to think with code before write it,, that my bad :( thanks

Comment: okey ,, but at least i must make it answered :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use only -  "OrElse " instead of OrElse NOT

Comment: thanks,, okey now here it edited in main post, thanks all,